# JSON to Java Object UTF_8

Tags: java, json, jackson

I`m using Jackson library to parse my java objects to/from json.
I have a problem, to parse text with "~".
Like: Questão.

I received:

```
Quest\u00c3\u00a3o
```

And after I use

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, targetClass);
```

I have this String on my Object Java: QuestÃ£o .

How can I convert this "Quest\u00c3\u00a3o" for this "Questão"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
String decodeStr = URLDecoder.decode("Quest\u00c3\u00a3o", "utf-8");
```

Comment: I try this:

String decodeStr = URLDecoder.decode("Quest\u00c3\u00a3o", "utf-8");
System.out.println("Decode: " + decodeStr);

this code print: QuestÃ£o

Comment: @leonvian You can use `java.net.URLEncoder`. `URLEncoder.encode("QuestÃ£o", "utf-8");`

Comment: The result for URLEncoder.encode("QuestÃ£o", "utf-8"); was: Quest%C3%83%C2%A3o

Comment: Is this your expected?`org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("QuestÃ£o")`